# Demo for Ionic with a Slide Menu and Tabs?

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm just beginning with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and AngularJS. I'm having trouble creating a mobile app that has both a slidemenu AND the bottom navigation tabs. Is there a demo/template/codepen for doing such a thing?

My code is here (all client-side): http://www.danhendricks.com/apps/soonhired/www/

When I click the top-left menu icon and the menu appears, clicking the links brings me nowhere - it simply closes the menu.

*I tried to put this in codepen or something similar, but since my files are in folders, I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: It brings the new pages when I click on the navigation tab buttons. Can you explain in more detail what actually you want?

Comment: It's the sliding menu links (when you click the triple-bar icon in the top-left header) that aren't working and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

danielh, i was looking for a solution to this problem and I've found your post. It might help to someone else.

http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/oaDhH

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content>
        <ul class="list">
            <a href="#/main/tab/home" class="item" ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = false">Home</a>
            <a href="#/main/tab/about" class="item"ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = false">About</a>
            <a href="#/main/tab/contact" class="item"ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = fakse">Contact</a>
            <a href="#/main/tab/feature" class="item" ng-click="mainCtrl.showFeature = true">Feature</a>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Comment: I think that your are missing one view in the "href"